# VB.net using strings in closed quote paths

Tags: vb.net

I'm struggling with how to use defined strings within closed quotes for example (""). I have two text boxes one for a IP or share name and one for a drive letter. When I press my button I want it to map the drive. Below is my code.

```
  Private Sub Button6_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button6.Click
        Dim drivePath As String = TextBox1.Text
        Dim driveLetter As String = TextBox2.Text

        Process.Start("cmd", "/k net use driveLetter drivePath")

    End Sub
```

I'm struggling with how I can use my driveLetter and drivePath strings within the arguments of

```
Process.Start("cmd", "/k .....")
```

Any help would be appreciated as I will need to do this sort of thing quite a lot.

Comment: `"/k net use " & driveLetter & " " & drivePath` is that what you mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a String's [Format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format.aspx) method for this purpose:

```
Process.Start("cmd", String.Format("/k net use {0} {1}", driveLetter, drivePath))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Private Sub Button6_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button6.Click        

    Dim drivePath As String = TextBox1.Text
    Dim driveLetter As String = TextBox2.Text

    Process.Start("cmd", "/k net use " & driveLetter & " " & drivePath)
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this, I hope this doesn't add any unnecessary spaces in to the line?